# Integration of new permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am trying to handle with the new permissions, introduced with API level 23.

I am calling a method in which I am passing some objects like bitmaps etc... In this method I am saving a bitmap to the sd card and the paths to the database.

With the new permissions I have to request the permission_group STORAGE. So far okay...

Am I right with the assumption, that I have to request the permission at the position I called the method earlier and my method have to move to the `onRequestPermissionsResult`? So every method call of something which needs permissions have to be in this method in the activity? That would be very anyoing because I have to handle how to pass all the objects to the `onRequestPermissionsResult` to put them finally in the method I wanted to call?

I hope I am wrong :D

EDIT:
Thanks to the sample app I could solve my problem. See my answer below.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/permissions/best-practices.html

Comment: And how does solve this my problem? My problem is that it would be ugly to move all the methods which needs permissions to this single method in the activity. Moreover how should I do this with bitmaps? I can not path the bitmap through intents or somethingelse

Comment: Checkout the sample app http://developer.android.com/intl/es/samples/RuntimePermissions/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Anoop. With this sample app I could solve my problem and the confusion the google developer post made.
And yes I was wrong. I need not to deal with all the stuff in the `onRequestPermissionResult` method.

- Instead of just calling your method request permission
- Dialog appears
- accept and press again the button to invoke your method

The method `onRequestPermissionResult` could be used to immediately fire your method after accepting the permission.

**My camera method call before:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,CameraUtility.getOutputMediaFileUri());
startActivityForResult(intent, ValueHolder.IntentResultCamera);
```

**My camera method with new permissions:**

```
if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.getMyAppCompatActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
   Permissions.requestCameraPerm(MainActivity.getMyAppCompatActivity());
} else {
   Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,CameraUtility.getOutputMediaFileUri());
   startActivityForResult(intent, ValueHolder.IntentResultCamera);
}
```

The `Permissions.requestCameraPerm` call:

```
public static void requestCameraPerm(final AppCompatActivity ac){

        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ac,Manifest.permission.CAMERA)){
            DrawerLayout mLayout = (DrawerLayout) ac.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

            Snackbar.make(mLayout, R.string.permission_camera_rationale,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction("Ok", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ac,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                    ValueHolder.REQUEST_CAMERA);
                        }
                    });


        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ac, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    ValueHolder.REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
    }
```

So to put it in a nutshell:
[Read this google tutorial](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/permissions/requesting.html) to understand what the new permissions is about
and use the methods they provide.

**BUT** do not be confused if they say, here... in the `onRequestPermissionResult` you can invoke your method which needed the permission. You **could** and probably **should** use this to immediately invoke your method after accepting the permission, but you **do not need** to. In some cases it is okay that the user has to press the button again.